# ffmpeg pipe blocks while capturing

Tags: java, ffmpeg, pipe, inputstream

I have this code:

```
public InputStream getInputStream() throws Exception {
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -f dshow -i video=\"" + query + "\":audio=\"" + microPhoneName + "\" -r 25 -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec mp3 -f avi -");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    return process.getInputStream();
}
```

When i use the `inputStream.read(b)` command, it works only for a little bit of times (180 to 400 times, depending from formats and codecs I use) then the `inputStream` lock on `read` and the application doesn't go anymore.

What's the problem? Memory saturation (ffmpeg process memory is at least 14mb)? 
Is there a way to unlock this situation (clean memory, use a file as a bridge to prevent locks)?

Of course I need a little bit of "realtime", and not "post-process".
I'm not constrained to use ffmpeg, I can change it if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by myself, after reading [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=3): the problem was that the `errorStream`was full and it had to be read to let the `process` to continue its work, so I inserted a `Thread` that consumes the `errorStream`:

```
public InputStream getInputStream() throws Exception {
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -f dshow -i video=\"" + query + "\":audio=\"" + microPhoneName + "\" -r 25 -vcodec mjpeg -acodec mp3 -f " + getContentExtension() + " -");
        new Thread("Webcam Process ErrorStream Consumer") {
            public void run() {
                InputStream i = process.getErrorStream();
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        i.read(new byte[bufferLength]);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return process.getInputStream();
}
```